# `db` including current character

Tags: normal-mode

When in normal mode, with the following (`^` indicates cursor position):

```
Lorem ipsum
          ^
```

How do I delete the entire word ipsum in the least keystrokes?

### Things I've Tried:

`db` gets

```
Lorem m
      ^
```

requiring an additional keypress of `x`.

Is there a way to do this with fewer keystrokes? If not, is there a way to do this in a single `d` command?

Comment: This youtube video on [mastering the vim language](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wlR5gYd6um0) gives a good overview of a lot of the core vim commands, as well as how they integrate into the 'big picture' of editing in Vim.

Answer (score 1):

Try `:h text-objects`.

For your case `diw` to delete "inner word" (without space) or `daw` to delete "a word" (with space).

Alternatively, you can use visual mode as with `vbd`.

Comment: Yes, indeed, typo :)

Answer (score 1):

```
dvb
```

See `:h o_v`. (5 more chars.)